# Strategy for backing up TFS 2008

Tags: backup, team-foundation-server, backupexec

I have Backup exec 2010 R2 running on Win2008 R2, and I need to backup TFS 2008.  I have about 10gb of TFS database files. From msdn articles I have read, all backups of the TFS databases must be time stamped the same or restoration will be impossible.

I am open to using backup exec, but I would like to avoid purchasing their SQL server agent since I am looking to move away from Backup Exec in the near future.  What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You could create you own SQL Server backups to disk, and then use backup Exec to backup those files.

The suggested approach to TFS backups are described on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253070(VS.90).aspx

(Note, the time synchronisation—or rather transaction synchronisation—is something new in TFS 2010.)

Comment: Ah, very good. I was not clear on whether or not TFS2008 has the same transaction synchronization requirements as TFS2010. 

However, in the backup guide in the link you provided, I did find the following information about TFS2008: "you might experience unexpected results after you restore from those back-ups because the databases are related and you risk restoring outdated versions."

I'm not sure what that means for my backup process... is it saying that I should backup ALL databases used by TFS?

Comment: Oh, and I should mention that this instance of TFS2008 must stay up 24/7.

Comment: @tm77: You should certainly back them all up (I thought that page said so). I cannot see why the process of flagging transactions used for 2010 (get the .NET 4 version of the same page) shouldn't work for TFS 2008. Probably worth asking MS support (if you need 24x7 ops you need a support contract).